# Timer Logic and Formatting in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have a database object `my_deal`, to which the date and time of a future point is set. This object has an attribute `deal_end`. I want to return the time remaining and format it as `DD:HH:MM`. For example, assuming that date and time is three days from this moment:

```
my_deal.deal_end
=> 02:23:59
```

I can't find a way to do this without installing some gem. Are there any ruby core methods that would make this easy?

Note: the way the time is stored in the database (and the method I use in the deals model) is as follows:

```
def end_time_set(days)
  end_time = (Date.today + days).to_s + " " + Time.now.to_s
  self.deal_end = end_time
  self.save
  return end_time
end
```

Comment: are you saving `deal_end` as a `String` in database? If so that can be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what your need:

```
my_deal.deal_end.strftime("%d:%H:%M")
```

Eg:

```
1.9.3p194 :002 > Time.now
 => 2013-10-14 15:33:56 -0500 
1.9.3p194 :003 > Time.now.strftime("%d:%H:%M")
 => "14:15:33" 
1.9.3p194 :004 >
```

[strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) has lot of other format options that you can use